# my google analytic Javascript code seems not to be working

Tags: html

Hello am new to google analytics and I want to use it to track traffics in my website , I followed all the procedures and got a code. I pasted the code in the head section but when I go back to report snapshots it is showing Users 0 am I missing something?
Here is my code

```
<head>
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-2Y6RFWP3ZF"></script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>ICT specialists</title>
<!-- *****animation link*** -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"/>
<!-- *****end of animation link*** -->
<!-- ----slick slider- links------ -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/slick.css">
<!-- ****bootstrap link**** -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- ****end bootstrap link**** -->
<!-- *******social-icons link*** -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- *******end social-icons link*** -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.css" />
<!-- *****aos link******************* -->
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-2Y6RFWP3ZF"></script>

<!-- ***css link*** -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
<!-- *****end css link**** -->
<!-- ***icon*** -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../img/logo/logo.png">
<!-- ***end of icon*** -->
</head>
```

and this is the analytics

Comment: Check the realtime report, does it show anything when you visit the page? If so it is working. The other reports will need time to gather data before showing anything.

Comment: It shows users in last 30 minutes '0" even when I visit my website

Comment: Do you use an adblocker?